# Springboot service communicate

Tags: java, spring-boot

In a springboot app what is the best way to communicate between @services?

I have a serviceA that handles some logic then sends some data to serviceB which has an executor to run some math and needs to then send an update to serviceA.

Currently I have a blockingqueue to send to from service A -> B, but this means the services would need to constantly monitor the queue when an object is on the queue... Would the applicationEvent publisher be useful here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically `@Service` is an Spring annotation to automate dependency management. This annotation does not mean that the class instance will be a service in meaning of " asynchronous service" (which, as I understand is your context). So to communicate two `@Service` annotated class instances, you need a reference of one of them in the other and, in asynchronous communication, provide some callback facility.

```
@Service
public class ServiceA{
   ServiceB serviceB;
  @Autowired      
  public ServiceA(ServiceB serviceB){
     this.serviceB = serviceB;
  }

  void foo(){
    serviceB.doTheJob();         
  }
 void jobDone() {
 {
}
```

Callback can be provided by dependency management injection of serviceA:

```
@Service
public class ServiceB{
   ServiceB serviceA;
  @Autowired      
  public ServiceA(ServiceA serviceA){
     this.serviceA = serviceA;
  }

  public void doTheJob() {
    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(() -> {/*do some job*/ 
                                                  serviceA.jobDone(););
  }

}
```

Or can be injected on method call (with, respectively modified `doTheJob` call):

```
@Service
public class ServiceB{
  public void doTheJob(ServiceA serviceA) {
    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(() -> {/*do some job*/ 
                                                  serviceA.jobDone(););
  }
}
```

Ofcourse above callback ways are only the examples and possibly in your context there is a need of using a queue.